# Talend ETL - running child job in tLoop

Tags: talend

I am trying to run a child job in tLoop. The child job connects to salesforce and downloads "Account" object to local SQL Server table. There are problems with connection to Salesforce, it takes few attempts to connect. Hence, I put the connection stuff in child job and now trying to call the child job in a loop. Below is the image of my parent job.

[image]

As you can see in image the tRunJob_1 has error because of Salesforce connection problem in child job. This is correct behaviour.

The setRetryConnect that is connected to OnComponentError has this code: `context.retryConnect = true;`

The setRetryConnect that is connected to OnComponentOk has this code: `context.retryConnect = false;`

So, I am tripping this context variable depending on whether child job succeeds or fails.

My tLoop looks as below:

[image]

I want the tLoop to run as many times till the condition remains true. That is till the time it continues to error out. However, it just iterates once and then stops. Could anyone please let me know what correction need to be done here to make the tLoop work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, posting it here so that it may help others. It appears like OnComponentError breaks the tLoop. Disabled the OnComponentError flow and un-checked the 'Die on Child Error' checkbox in tRunJob.

[image: parent job]

[image: tRunJob]

The tLoop remains as it is. No changes here.

[image: tLoop]

The retryConnect will use the below code. It uses CHILD_RETURN_CODE to check whether the child job threw error. In case of success, its value is 0. I am tripping the variable when the child job succeeds, so the loop will stop. As you can see, the tLoop shows 2 iterations, it is working as expected now. Thanks.

[image: retryConnect]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't re-pro your issue with `SalesForce` but by looking at your job what I feel is that when you say - "it just iterates once and then stops" is the expected behavior.

As per your job flow after the `tRunJob` you are using `OnComponentOk/OnComponentError` trigger which would process and stop the job run as it would have completed the job execution. What it would have ideal was to keep everything in a `subjob` post `tLoop` so that it will iterate till the condition is met.

Sample job for explanation - 
[image]

Here used `tSetGlobalVar` to define a global variable (in place of your context variable). Then use the globalMap variable as `((Boolean)globalMap.get("tLoop"))` in your "Condition" for the `tLoop`.

And then finally run some code in the `tJava` component that does something and conditionally sets the global variable to false to mark the ending of loop.
`tRunJob` provides an Return Code `((Integer)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_CHILD_RETURN_CODE"))`
If you're running your child Job a number of times and want your Job to exit with non-Zero if one of these iterations fails, then after each iteration, you should test this return code and store it in your own globalMap Object if it is non-zero

```
int returnCode = ((Integer)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_CHILD_RETURN_CODE"));
if (returnCode > 0) {
    globalMap.put("tLoop", false);
} 
else {
    System.out.println(returnCode);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but OnComponentOk does not stop the tLoop. Moreover, as you can see in your image, the tRunJob gives warning that 'no schema is defined' because you are using the main row to continue the flow.

Comment: Great you made it work, the tRunJob was giving an error because I hadn't defined any schema nor selected any child job which could had used it own schema in the tRunJob. I had completely forgotten to mention about unchecking the 'Die on Child Error' in tRunJob - good catch.